# How to call a variable inside of for loop?

Tags: java, scope

I can't seem to access `randElement1`, `randElement2` and `randElement3` which are defined within the 3 loops I have created.

My programme creates a string that has 3 random elements chosen from a list.

I know this is a simple problem and I did look it up. I have read all about Scopes, but I can't even find a solution to my specific coding problem. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner userInput = new 
    Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();

//Insult Bank
    String[] shakeInsults3 = new String[].{"scut", "apple-john", "baggage", "barnacle", "bladder", "boar-pig", "bugbear", "codpiece","flap-dragon", "giglet", "horn-beast","jolthead","wagtail","scut","pignut","vassal","moldwarp","lout","lewdster","measle","minnow","pumpion","ratsbane","varlet","maggot-pie","harpy"};

    String[] shakeInsults1 = new String[]{"artless", "bawdy", "beslubbering","bootless", "churlish", "cockered", "clouted", "craven", "currish", "dankish", "dissembling", "droning", "errant", "fawning", "fobbing", "froward", "frothy", "gleeking", "goatish", "gozbellied", "impertinent", "infectious", "jarring", "loggerheaded", "lumpish", "mammering", "mangled", "mewling", "paunchy", "pribbling", "puking", "puny", "quailing", "rank", "reeky", "roguish", "ruttish", "saucy", "spleeny", "spongy", "surly", "tottering", "unnuzzled", "vain", "venomed", "villainous", "warped", "wayward", "weedy", "yeasty"};

    String[] shakeInsults2 = new String[]{"base-court", "bat-fowling", "beef-witted", "beetle-headed", "boil-brained", "clapper-clawed", "clay-brained", "common-kissing", "crooked=pated", "dismal-dreaming", "dizzy-eyed","elf skinned", "fat=kidneyed", "fen-sucked", "fool-born", "half-faced", "hell-hated", "onion-eyed", "swag-bellied","reeling-ripe","rude-growing","ill-nurtured","guts-griping","shard-borne"};

//declaring
    int intRandomWord1 = shakeInsults1.length;
    int intRandomWord2 = shakeInsults2.length;
    int intRandomWord3 = shakeInsults3.length;


    for (int s = 0; s < 1; s++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < intRandomWord1; i++) {
          int randIndex1 = (int)(Math.random() * shakeInsults1.length);
          String randElement1 = shakeInsults1[randIndex1];       
  }

      for (int i = 0; i < intRandomWord2; i++) {
          int randIndex2 = (int)(Math.random() * shakeInsults2.length); 
          String randElement2 = shakeInsults2[randIndex2];

      }

      for (int i = 0; i < intRandomWord3; i++) {
          int randIndex3 = (int)(Math.random() * shakeInsults3.length); 
          String randElement3 = shakeInsults3[randIndex3];
      }
    }
    System.out.println("Thou ", + randElement1, ", " + randElement2 + ", " + randElement3 + ".");


  }


}
```

Comment: Declare the variables outside the loops. When you declare them inside the loop, they go out of scope as soon as the loop ends.

Comment: You can't "call" a variable. Methods are called. Variables are used.

Comment: You're creating them inside the for loops. You have to create them before the for loop and then initialize them outside of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do (although I can't test it on my machine right now, sorry.) Be aware that Random is only a pseudo random number generator and shouldn't be used when true randomness is required.  Any variable declared inside of a loop will not exist outside of the loop.  This will generate a new string for randElement1, 2, and 3 every pass of the loop.

```
   // This is so you don't get index out of bounds errors if the lists are different lengths.
   // You could combine these into one line with nested Math.min calls.
   // I made it two lines to be easier for you to read.
   int minListLength = Math.min(shakeInsults1.length, shakeInsults2.length);
   minListLength = Math.min(minListLength, shakeInsults3.length);

   for (int s = 0; s < minListLength; s++) {

          String randElement1 = shakeInsults1[rand.nextInt(shakeInsults1.length)];       

          String randElement2 = shakeInsults2[rand.nextInt(shakeInsults2.length)];

          String randElement3 = shakeInsults3[rand.nextInt(shakeInsults3.length)];

          System.out.println("Thou ", + randElement1, ", " + randElement2 + ", " + randElement3 + ".");

  }
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Programming in Java is soooo different to python as far as scopes go. Again, thanks!

Comment: Question. I can't seem to find how to use array functions in Java. All I ever get is how to use the Arraylist library which I don't want to use. Where can I learn about Arrays etc.

Comment: Arrays are very basic in Java so they don't have functions.  You can do some manipulation of arrays with the Arrays class like copying and sorting.  ArrayList can be very powerful because it has more functions, it's backed by an array, and it can be combined with Collections methods for even more functionality.

Comment: Right, wrong word. Meant manipulation. Thanks for the clarification! Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Initiate them outside of the for loop

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize a variable inside a loop and use it outside, if you want to use it outside you must declare it inside the method where you want to use it. <3

Answer (score 1):

So try this and let me know how it goes.

```
int randIndex1 = 0;
String randElement1 = "";

int randIndex2 = 0;
String randElement2 = "";

int randIndex3 = 0;
String randElement3 = "";

for (int s = 0; s < 1; s++) 
{
  for (int i = 0; i < intRandomWord1; i++) 
  {
      randIndex1 = (int)(Math.random() * shakeInsults1.length);
      randElement1 = shakeInsults1[randIndex1];       
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < intRandomWord2; i++) 
  {
      randIndex2 = (int)(Math.random() * shakeInsults2.length); 
      randElement2 = shakeInsults2[randIndex2];

  }

  for (int i = 0; i < intRandomWord3; i++) 
  {
      randIndex3 = (int)(Math.random() * shakeInsults3.length); 
      randElement3 = shakeInsults3[randIndex3];
  }
}
```

I hope that helps. I don't know if you're trying to add any values or return anything. Comment if something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because you **declared** the variables inside of the for loops, their scope is limited to inside the for loops. To access them outside the for loops, you will have to declare them outside of the for loops. You can try something similar to this:

```
int intRandomWord1 = shakeInsults1.length;
  int intRandomWord2 = shakeInsults2.length;
  int intRandomWord3 = shakeInsults3.length;

  String randElement1;
  String randElement2;
  String randElement3;


  for (int i = 0; i < intRandomWord1; i++) {
      int randIndex1 = (int)(Math.random() * shakeInsults1.length);
      randElement1 = shakeInsults1[randIndex1];       
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < intRandomWord2; i++) {
      int randIndex2 = (int)(Math.random() * shakeInsults2.length); 
      randElement2 = shakeInsults2[randIndex2];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < intRandomWord3; i++) {
      int randIndex3 = (int)(Math.random() * shakeInsults3.length); 
      randElement3 = shakeInsults3[randIndex3];
}
```

You actually don't need for loops for this solution. To program this without for loops, try something similar to what Bakon Jarser suggested.